# Flyway timeout, backoff, and retry

Tags: flyway

I'm running Flyway v4.0.3 against a Postgres databases. Occasionally, we have mirations that will fail due to things like not being able to acquire a lock or we will put a lock_timeout into the migration which will fail if the timeout limit is reached.

Does flyway have a way during certain failures, like a timeout limit being reached,to backoff and wait for a few seconds and then retry the migration N number of times before hard failing?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Flyway documentation, particularly the [config settings](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configfiles), I don't see any option that would allow you to do that.

However it would probably be possible to use [Java migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#java-based-migrations) to achieve this. You could write a base class which has the 'retry N times' behavior. Each of your migrations could then inherit from that class in order to get this behavior.

Hope that is of some help.